# .NET Core View property name different from model property name

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have an ajax function that returns an error message to a field when an error occurs serverside.

This is how I show my errors:

```
$.each(result.errors, function (index, item) {
    // Get message placeholder
    var element = $('[data-valmsg-for="' + item.propertyName + '"]');
    element.empty();
    // Update message
    element.append($('<span></span>').text(item.errorMessage));
    // Update class names
    element.removeClass('field-validation-valid').addClass('field-validation-error');
    $('#' + item.propertyName).removeClass('valid').addClass('input-validation-error');
});
```

This is supposed to read the returned propertyname which is the name of my field and display the message on it.

This is the field. It is a dropdownlist

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.UserId)
            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.BranchDropdownListViewModel.BranchId, Model.BranchDropdownListViewModel.Branch, "Select Branch", new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.BranchDropdownListViewModel.BranchId)
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I inspect the code, the name of this dropdown is BranchDropdownListViewModel.BranchId

However, in my controller when I try to find the name of this field like this:

```
ModelState.AddModelError(nameof(Input.BranchDropdownListViewModel.BranchId), "Branch already exists");
```

It shows BranchId as the name of the field only.

This is the model:

```
public class UserBranchDetailsViewModel
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public string TenantId { get; set; }
    public BranchDropdownListViewModel BranchDropdownListViewModel { get; set; }
}

public class BranchDropdownListViewModel
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Branch")]
    public string BranchId { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Branch { get; set; }
}
```

How can I match the name shown in the view from the controller? Must I do it manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The use of the nameof would only produce the last part of the property name, which in your case is `BranchId`.

Since getting an injected `HtmlHelper` is not so straightforward, I would suggest you to do

```
ModelState.AddModelError($"{nameof(Input.BranchDropdownListViewModel)}.{nameof(Input.BranchDropdownListViewModel.BranchId)}", "Branch already exists");
```

But if you really want to use the `HtmlHelper`, look at this [method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.viewfeatures.htmlhelper-1.namefor?view=aspnetcore-3.1) `HtmlHelper.NameFor()`.